# inflateexception mapview android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm using fragment sliding menu in my application. I want to implement mapview for fragment.
But I'm getting inflate exception. How to resolve it.
Note : In manifest file I provide all the permissions as well.I generated API key also for this. I tried to apply Supportmapfragment and sherlockFragment but It requires LocationFragment insteadof fragment. But I want mapview in fragment only.

My code for mapview is..

```
   public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {
private static View view;
MapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap map;
ImageView iv;
public LocationFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }

    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_info, container,
                false);

        mapFragment = ((MapFragment) this.getActivity()
                .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);

        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Problems inflating the view !",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services missing !",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return view;
}}
```

XML layout is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
      <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Output is.. **Problems inflating the view !**

Please help on it. Thanks in advance.

Error log is:

```
08-25 18:04:10.420: W/dalvikvm(25577): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413ef9a8)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.example.bulidersapp.LocationFragment.onCreateView(LocationFragment.java:24)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577): Caused by:      java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does   not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4734)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
08-25 18:04:10.432: E/AndroidRuntime(25577):    ... 19 more
```

Manifest file added items...

```
      <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<permission
     android:name="com.example.bulidersapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission  android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
   <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

and inside application

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="--my application app key---" />
```

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: check my code.. from that I got InflateException from thread.

Comment: Post the **full** error message.

Comment: view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_info, container,
                false); error in this line.

Comment: Good :) Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your `AndroidManifest.xml` file application tags add the google maps meta tag, like this:

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    ...
</application>
```